# Don't know if i'm seeing theory about wrapper method straight

Tags: jquery, theory

Here's the code the piece of theory is about

```
$.fn greenify = function(){
 return this.css ('color','green');
}
```

so this can be used as follows

```
$('#today').greenify();
```

then, the theory says:

*"A wrapper method must always return the original set, hence the `return this`. This way you can use your method in a chain."*

To me, a wrapper method so far I saw as a way to target multiple HTML elements. Does it simply mean that if you target those elements, you actually get those targeted HTML elements just as they are, unmodified? So that when you say return this, you want to confirm you know exactly what you're getting so you know what you're using when you're chaining? Or does it mean something different?

Comment: without the context of your quote, it will be difficult to answer. Where did it come from ? Is it the only relevant part ?

Comment: sorry about that. I changed my question with code that gives context.

Comment: The example would work very well even without any return in the code of `greenify()`. And what is returned isn't `this` it is the returned value of `this.css('color', 'green')` I think you should ask your professor or really improve your question ;)

Comment: But `this.css` returns `this` because most jQuery methods **are** chainable. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A wrapper method basically means that

> For any selector s and any method
>   `method` . $(s).method() === $(s)

In your case you want

```
$.fn greenify = function(){
 return this.each(function() {
  this.css("color", "green");
 });
}
```

Here your method modifies the colour of every dom element in the set. And you can already assert that `this.each` as a method on a jQuery object `$(s)` will return the set `$(s)` so your method also returns `$(s)`.

Of course for simplicity sake your function does the same because `$.fn.css` is optimised to work on a set under the hood. For clarity were calling `$.fn.each` ourself rather then having `$.fn.css` call it for us.